# Error in adding vuetify on a project

Tags: npm, vuejs2, vuetify.js, fsevents

I have created a `vue-cli` project.

And I tried to add **vuetify** but I couldn't do it

I've run: `npm install vuetify --save`

A error came out on terminal:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.1.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.3 (node_modules/sane/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

When I try to import **vuetify** on `main.js` it says that can't find the module.

Does anyone know how to fix/install it?

Comment: why not just use "vue init vuetifyjs/webpack-simple project_name" ?

Comment: This is a an issue not specific to vue. What versions of npm and node do you have?

Comment: are you trying to install this on MacOS? If so, you may want to include that on the tags

Comment: This is a simple warning, you can definitely ignore it (except if you're on MacOS)

Comment: I was not installing it on MacOS @JamesAMohler

Comment: I didn't know that there is a template on vue-cli with vuetifyjs. @divine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try using yarn, I find it sometimes performs better

install yarn
`npm i -g yarn`

Then install dependencies (run in your `package.json` file folder)
`yarn`

You can also do a clean install by first removing the nodes_modules folder, and then install without optional dependencies `npm install --no-optional`

Comment: also, make sure you don't have `npm run dev` running while you do this